# How to dynamically rename an object file in a makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, multiple-makefiles

I am very very new to makefiles. The most complex task I had done before was to include new .h and and .cpp or .c in already designed makefiles.

I have to port the compilation process of a project from Visual Studio to gcc and there is an already made solution for this written by a colleague but he used 4 bash scripts and a makefile to compile the solution.

Instead of doing that I was looking for solutions to make it easier to maintain. My question may be very dumb I admit, but I could not find it anywhere nor I could  understand it all properly.

In the target below:

```
$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.cpp 
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

I would like to test if the .o being created already exists and rename it to something else. This is necessary because in the project there are several source files that have the same name yet they are different in content.

For example, if the current .cpp being compiled is called file.cpp and the object that will be generated is file.o, the rule should test whether file.o already exists and rename the current file.o to something else.

If you know any good tutorial that explains this, please let me know. I found lots of examples that show how to make tests for the current file being compiled by that rule, but none that would rename the object .o.

Thanks in advance and sorry for any "dumbness" written here. :-)

Comment: What I've done in the past is to place object files in the same directory hierarchy as the source files. I guess you have files on different levels with the same name?

Comment: @Max , yes. There are two different directories, with source files named like file1.cpp file2.cpp etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have our deep sympathy.

Make is not really designed to handle such ambiguity, so we'll have to use a kludge. You haven't said what you want to rename the file *to*, so for now lets say we move `file.o` to `file_save.o`.

```
# This tells Make that these are not real targets, so that it will
# proceed even if file.o already exists.
.PHONY: $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.cpp 
    # If file.o exists, move it to file_save.o
    @if [ -f $@ ]; then mv $@ $*_save.o; fi
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Hey, many thanks. This code seems to work, however the *_save.o files are not being generated. I think that is because my source cpp file are defined in a variable `SOURCE = file1.cpp file2.cpp file1.cpp` and then I used `OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)` to create the OBJECTS rule.

Comment: Really? That shouldn't matter... Replace the `if` line with this and see what happens: `mv $@ $*_save.o`. It  will complain the first time, when there is no `file.o` to move, but otherwise it will do the same thing and tell you what it's doing.

Comment: Thanks for the help! When i try it, make aborts the compilation right after the first .o not found.

Comment: @xlogdan: Ack! Sorry, I should have said `-mv $@ $*_save.o`. And try with just one `file.o` at first, not the whole `OBJECTS` list.

Comment: @Beta , thanks a lot for the help! It still does not show any effect, make complains that I included two equal targets in the same rule and it won't execute the above command because there is no .o. Anyway, I apologize for this whole mess, but I made it work compiling the sources that have equal names in batch file, I just specify that each file will have a different .o name. Next I call the makefile that will bundle everything in a static library. I don't have more time on this, so unfortunately I will have to let it as it is, at least I reduced it from 5 bash scripts to 1 plus a make file.

Comment: @Anyway, thanks for the help and I apologize. I plan to get back to this if I get time.

Answer (score 1):

Expansion of my comment on the question:

Perhaps you should consider placing object files in the same directory hieryarchy as the source files, to prevent naming conflicts.

So that src/network/client.cpp is compiled to build/obj/network/client.o.

I'm extremely rusty when it comes to makefiles but I believe I solved that by doing something like:

```
$SRC= src/network/client.cpp src/main.cpp .....
$OBJ= makefile_replace_function($SRC, .o)

$(OBJ) : $(SRC)
   compile_instructions
```

Where you will have to replace `makefile_replace_function` and `compile_instructions` to their real equivalents since I have forgotten then...

I realize this might not be very helpful but atleast its an idea to consider.